# How to make sexy bookmarks plugin work in WPMU

Tags: plugins, customization, multisite

We have Wordpress 3.0 working as multi site, and we want all the blogs in the system to have the plugin "[sexy bookmarks](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/sexybookmarks/)". But it seems to be working only in the main blog.
Does anyone know how to make it work in all blogs (what code to add to make it work that way)? Or is there a plugin like sexy bookmarks that adds social network icons to each post that works in a multi site version of Wordpress 3.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the plugin is alreayd activated, then you cannot network activate it. because you already turned it on. Turn it off. Network activate it.

You still have to configure it for each blog.

Comment: Thank you so much! Turning it off helped. Do you know if there's a way to do a bulk configuration for all blogs? Because we can't manually configure every blog created on the site...

Comment: there's a handful of plugins to set up blog templates to replicate the settings from plugins across all newly created blogs.

Answer (score 1):

have you 'network' activated it? You may have to deactivate it then use the Network activate it.

Comment: That's the problem - it doesn't have a Network activation! The question is if there is a way that I can add code to the plugin in order to add a Network activation option

Comment: I'd clarify that in the question then. You don't state that there is no network option so it's not clear that you're aware of it and it doesn't exist. I know network activation tripped me up at first.